# Is there an equivalent of Memtest86 for CPUs?

Tags: cpu, memory, overclocking, benchmarking

I need an easy way to do system stability tests. I have come to rely on Prime95 which does a fantastic job of proving stability (or instability) very quickly; but it requires an OS installed.

I would like something like Prime95 that stresses both CPU and RAM (maybe PCI-Ex bus also?) but runs in a nice bootable binary like Memtest86+ does, so I can boot it from a thumbdrive.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: The question seems super legit to me, got 21 upvotes, viewed 24k times but some mod who was having a bad day decided to close it for 'off-topic', classic. Anyway OP, thanks for asking this question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it was said, [ubcd4win](http://ubcd4win.org) with the integrated prime95 is a good solution.

For a lighter solution you could use this linux distribution: [stresslinux](http://www.stresslinux.org/sl/)

- stresslinux is a minimal linux distribution running from a bootable cdrom, usb, vmware or via PXE (wip).
- stresslinux makes use of some utitlities available on the net like: stress, cpuburn, hddtemp, lm_sensors, memtest386+ ...
- stresslinux is dedicated to users who want to test their system(s) entirely on high load and monitoring the health.

But you should be familiar with command line (& linux console) because it comes without a graphical user interface.

**Update:**

You could also [add .Net framework](http://colinfinck.de/en/peplugs/dotnetfx20pe/) to ubcd4win to use [IntelBurnTest](http://downloads.guru3d.com/IntelBurnTest-v2.3-download-2047.html) (works with amd too) - **I don't have it properly tested yet, but it should work**

1. Add the cab file for the .net framework: `plugins > add`
2. Just uncompress IntelBurnTest in a directory like C:\My_UBCD4Win_Custom_Files and add this directory in `"Custom: (include files or folders from this directory)"`. If it doesn't work or you want to create shortcuts: you could find instructions & tools here "[Robvdb how plugin](http://users.telenet.be/Robvdb/how_plugin.htm)" and "royalbox's barts pe plugin creator" [here](http://www.hallsted.us/barts-pe-plugins-mlh/barts-pe-plugins-mlh.html)

Comment: stresslinux is perfect. Exactly what I need.

Comment: @fluxtendu: How would I go about building IntelBurnTest into UBCD4Win? I've been looking at this (http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/help/english/pluginformat.htm#Introduction) but I haven't figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: @Ssvarc look at my update...

Comment: Thanks for the directions! I plan on trying it in the next 2 weeks and will try to update with the results.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download.html).

Download and burn the ISO into a CD or put the contents into a bootable thumb drive.
Boot from the CD/thumb drive.

From the options which has several tools, you could select mainboard tools and then StressCPU test from there to stress test your CPU.

Check [this](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/), for the list of tools available in this ISO.

Comment: Could you please add some more detail on how to use UB-CD to solve his problem?

Comment: Now you're answer is worthy of my upvote ;-) Thanks for editing!

Comment: Wow, very nice collection there. Personally looking for something a little more lightweight though.

Answer (score 3):

You can run something like [BartPe](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/). There is even a version that has the plugins already installed called [UBCD4Win](http://www.ubcd4win.com/). Sure enough, they have [Prime95](http://www.ubcd4win.com/verhistory.htm) in there as well. And it can run from a [USB](http://ubcd4win.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=11445) [stick](http://ubcd4win.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=11375). (Based on info [here](http://ubcd4win.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=9630) it appears the second method is the better/easier one. YMMV)

Enjoy, and happy computing!

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is [Overclockix](http://www.overclockix.com/)